# Export vertex colors in .abc alembic

Tags: export, vertex-colors, alembic

I am unable to export an alembic with vertex colours.
I have a cube with some vertex colours on it that I would like to export as an alembic but on reimport, in a different file, the colour attribute has disappeared. Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for helping out :)